# How to forcefully fail my azure pipeline CI/CD

Tags: azure-pipelines

I Implemented some azure pipeline task where in some certain conditions build steps will not perform i.e It will be skipped.

I am wondering how to fail those skipped steps forcefully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to forcefully failed my azure pipeline CI/CD

There is no such method to  failed those skipped build steps forcefully. Because this behavior is **by designed**.

Since certain conditions build steps are skipped, those build steps are not executed, so their most appropriate state should be skipped, not Failed.

As workaround, we could add a Powershell task with following scripts to fail build from a task:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=agent.jobstatus;]Failed"
Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]DONE"
```

[image]

But another challenge is that there is no directly condition, so that we could execute above powershell task after previous skipped task:

[image]

It only provide the condition succeeded or Failed.

So, we still need to get the result of previous task by Rest API in this PowerShell task, then executed above powershell scripts based on the result of previous task:

You can check this thread [How to get reason for failure of a previous task in vsts CI build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889315/how-to-get-reason-for-failure-of-a-previous-task-in-vsts-ci-build) for some more details.

If above workaround is not concise for you, I add a uservoice to add more condition in the task, like previousstatus=skipped, succeededwithwarning on our main forum for product suggestions:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/660602/add-more-condition-for-build-task.html

You can vote it and track the feedback from it.

Hope this helps.